# How to control/check gpio states with shell commands (at91sam9260 board)

Tags: linux, shell, embedded

I need to write a script that controls and checks the gpio states.

I have been trying for a while to find a way to do it, but I didn't succeed.

Here is for the details : 
I use an at91sam9260 board with a Linux kernel 2.6.27 embedded in it.

I see the /dev/gpio device 
I tried some commands like cat /dev/gpio OR echo 1> /dev/gpio but it did not give me any result ( except an error message for the first command)

I also tried to create /dev/gpio0 .. to /dev/gpio31 (with the makedev command before recompiling the CRAMFS filesystem, but I did not get more results.

Does someone know how to check these gpio states and set/clear some of them ?

More generally, Is there an easy way to find out the proper shell commands for a particular device just by looking at the driver source files ?

Answer (score 3):

If your kernel has sysfs support you can access and control the gpio pins through the interface in `/sys/class/gpio`.  See the sysfs section of the kernel [document](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/gpio.txt?v=2.6.27) in `Documentation/gpio.txt`.

Comment: Could you be more explicit ? for example, if i read correctly the doc, "echo 19 > /sys/class/gpio/export" will create a gpio19 node, "echo x > (cat) /sys/class/gpio/gpio19/direction" will set x (get) direction and "echo x > (cat) /sys/class/gpio/gpio19/value" will set x (get) value

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this stuff but I think you've got the idea.  In your example x should either 0 or 1.  Have you tried it?  Does it work for you?

Comment: I doesnt work on my board(cheap mips something), it has a gpio that control a blinking led, and it's look like the gpio device control the frequency of the blinking, not the status of the led ...

Comment: @JulienFr: Perhaps your system uses the leds device class to manage that LED.  In that case I think it would override the gpio class.  Checkout [this kernel document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/leds/leds-class.txt)

Comment: Whooo !! thanks so much, Sean (even if SO forbids thanking ...)

Answer (score 0):

I have used at91sam9260. You can set/unset the gpio pins using sysfs interface.
for ex. go to: cd /sys/class/gpio and then "echo 2 > export" and then set the directions of gpio pins to input(in)/output(out) by "echo in > direction" and then you can read the value from "value" file by "cat value"

Answer (score 0):

Check `/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/` directory for verbose GPIO info.